# Binning to discretize a numeric variable in python

Tags: python, binning

I want to bin my numeric variable of a data frame so it becomes a categorical variable. The values in my variable range from 1-16 and here you can see the output value count of it here.

```
2     23660
4     11051
1      6911
6      4350
3      3876
5      2596
8      1198
7       781
10      291
9       241
12      107
16       51
11       50
14       38
13       25
15       13
```

I want to bin every value bigger than 8 to the string value '8+'.

I tried the following code:

```
df['var1_binned'] = pd.cut(df['var1'], bins=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], labels=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8+'])
print(df['var1_binned'].value_counts())
```

but I only received the following Output:

```
2     23660
4     11051
1      6911
6      4350
3      3876
5      2596
8+     1198
7       781
Name: var1_binned, dtype: int64
```

Somehow it only labeled every row with a value from 1-8 but excluded everything above 8 completely.
Could someone help?

Comment: Aside from the linked duplicate, please also [read the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and think carefully about the logic. Does `cut` work with exact values, or with intervals? When you wrote your existing attempt, why did you need to include `0` in the `bins`? What happens if you only specify a single value in the `bins` list?